# Intel VTune not displaying symbols and source on Windows captures

Tags: windows, intel-vtune

Intel VTune is not displaying symbols or source when reviewing a capture. I'm building with Visual Studio on Windows, and running the capture through there. I can see my process and some functions being called in VTune but there's no more information.
[image]

I've read the documentation and followed the troubleshooting guides but with no luck.

- PDB is correctly being generated in the same directory as the binary, with the same name (application is compiled with /Zi and /DEBUG)
- File paths specified at the start of the capture are correct
- I've specified custom local directories for binary/source paths. According to [their docs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/user-guide/2024-0/search-order.html) it shouldn't even need this as it can search the location where the binary is

Finalization is complete without errors

```
Finalization completed successfully

Jan 07 2024 18:57:26 Result is ready for analysis.
```

Are there any other steps that I'm missing to enable the correct source/callstack in the profiler?